# Pairwise vdot using Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I'm trying to compute the pairwise `np.vdot` of a complex 2D array `x` with itself. So the behaviour I want is:

```
X = np.empty((x.shape[0], x.shape[0]), dtype='complex128')
for i in range(x.shape[0]):
    for j in range(x.shape[0]):
        X[i, j] = np.vdot(x[i], x[j])
```

Is there a way to do this without the explicit loops? I tried using `pairwise_kernel` from `sklearn` but it assumes the input arrays are real numbers. I also tried broadcasting, but `vdot` flattens its inputs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
X = np.einsum('ik,jk->ij', np.conj(x), x)
```

is equivalent to

```
X = np.empty((x.shape[0], x.shape[0]), dtype='complex128')
for i in range(x.shape[0]):
    for j in range(x.shape[0]):
        X[i, j] = np.vdot(x[i], x[j])
```

[`np.einsum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html)
takes a sum of products. The subscript `'ik,jk->ij'` tells `np.einsum` that the second argument,
`np.conj(x)` is an array with subscripts `ik` and the third argument, `x` has
subscripts `jk`. Thus, the product `np.conj(x)[i,k]*x[j,k]` is computed for all
`i`,`j`,`k`.  The sum is taken over the repeated subscript, `k`, and since that
leaves `i` and `j` remaining, they become the subscripts of the resultant array.

---

For example,

```
import numpy as np

N, M = 10, 20
a = np.random.random((N,M))
b = np.random.random((N,M))
x = a + b*1j

def orig(x):
    X = np.empty((x.shape[0], x.shape[0]), dtype='complex128')
    for i in range(x.shape[0]):
        for j in range(x.shape[0]):
            X[i, j] = np.vdot(x[i], x[j])
    return X

def alt(x):
    return np.einsum('ik,jk->ij', np.conj(x), x)

assert np.allclose(orig(x), alt(x))
```

---

```
In [307]: %timeit orig(x)
10000 loops, best of 3: 143 µs per loop

In [308]: %timeit alt(x)
100000 loops, best of 3: 8.63 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 4):

To extend the `np.vdot` to all rows, you can use [`np.tensordot`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.tensordot.html) and I am borrowing the conjugate idea straight off [`@unutbu's solution`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36490006/3293881) , like so -

```
np.tensordot(np.conj(x),x,axes=(1,1))
```

Basically with `np.tensordot`, we specify the axes to be reduced, which in this case is the last axis for the conjugate version of `x` and the array itself, when applied on those two.

Runtime test -

Let's time [`@unutbu's` solution with `np.einsum`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36490006/3293881) and the proposed solution in this post -

```
In [27]: import numpy as np # From @unutbu's` solution again
    ...: 
    ...: N, M = 1000, 1000
    ...: a = np.random.random((N,M))
    ...: b = np.random.random((N,M))
    ...: x = a + b*1j
    ...: 

In [28]: %timeit np.einsum('ik,jk->ij', np.conj(x), x) # @unutbu's` solution
1 loops, best of 3: 4.45 s per loop

In [29]: %timeit np.tensordot(np.conj(x),x,axes=(1,1))
1 loops, best of 3: 3.76 s per loop
```